# No visible leaves on Pokemon go screen

Tags: pokemon-go

I don't see any leaves going up anywhere on Pokemon. Why did my leaves disappear?

I've restarted my phone, still no leaves.

Comment: Guess then there's no pokemon. Unless P-Go hasn't made an official release and you downloaded the app "illegally" online.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes leaves **simply don't appear**.

They're not guaranteed to be there, nor are they guaranteed to be in the same spot every time.

Most importantly, [Pokemon aren't guaranteed to spawn where you see leaves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/274206/125786).