# Pokemon leaves won't appear

Tags: pokemon-go

There is just a lack of leaves on all the map even tough i do have pokemon nearby it makes no sense also my version is 0.33.0 and 5.1 android

Comment: they removed it

Comment: @Aequitas I know they removed the tracker, but did they also remove the little green rustles of leaves on the map? Perhaps that's what this question is referring to

Answer (score 4):

Initially, the [leaves](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272708/do-these-leaves-signify-anything) were used as a way to identify a possible Pokémon location - that is, an identifier to indicate where you *might* encounter a Pokémon.

**This has since been removed in the last few updates.** (Prior to 0.33.0 on Android)

The explanation as to why however, is lacking, so speculation abounds.

- It is likely that [since the changes to the "Nearby" tracking system](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/update-080816/) have been implemented, this identifier is no longer relevant.
- It is also possible that this was fairly useless to most users anyway, as there have been many reports all over the internet that this feature reaped no rewards.
- Since there has been no proof to say exactly what this was for, it is entirely possible that this was purely aesthetic, and the user speculation created a theory about how it had some sort of in-game function. In this case, I don't see why Niantic would leave it in game if it was creating nothing but confusion and frustration in the user population.