# Why am I not seeing footprints and piles of leaves in Pokémon Go anymore?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why can't I see piles of leaves in my map area? Additionally, in the "Nearby Pokémon" there should be footprints underneath them indicating how far away they are, and nothing is showing on mine (it's not because I'm to far away from them, I never have footprints). Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: There was an update nearly two months ago that replaced the footprint system. There is no way to tell distance at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for that, I did have the update but I thought something had gone wrong with it, cheers again

Answer (score 2):

From the list of [updates for Android](http://nintendonews.com/pokemon-go-update-history-android/) (iOS dates may differ):

> Version 0.31.0 – July 30, 2016
>
> - Avatars can now be re-customized from the Trainer profile screen
> - Adjusted battle move damage values for some Pokémon
> - Refined certain Gym animations
> - Improved memory issues
> - **Removed footprints of nearby Pokémon**
> - Modified battle damage calculation
> - Various bug fixes during wild Pokémon encounter
> - Updated Pokémon details screen
> - Updated achievement medal images
> - Fixed issues with displaying certain map features
> - Minor text fixes

The ["leaves" were removed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/281361/73976) around the same time, yet it was not specifically listed in the updates (possibly due to the assumption in was somehow linked to the "nearby" tracking system).